# xml game info secure on mobile?

Tags: android, xml, mobile, blackberry-playbook

I've never made a game for a mobile so I'm not really sure what the proper convention for level info is. Basically I'm thinking that I include an xml file that I add to local diskspace for the app then load the level details (item positions, etc) from that xml file, this way when I have to update the game, add more levels, I only have the users download a small xml file. Is this method secure or are there other ways of doing this?

Comment: 1) I don't want the users to change the xml file and basically make the level easy 
2) also, it would be nice that users don't see what type of level they can expect. basically I don't want read and write access on the xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The security features on the BlackBerry can be pretty complicated, check out the second half of this article for a good summary of the various security features available:
http://programming4.us/mobile/2694.aspx

Here are some official BlackBerry docs on the topic too:
http://docs.blackberry.com/en/smartphone_users/deliverables/1487/Security_26381_11.jsp

FYI, most of this information concentrates on protecting data from unauthorized users, or from other malicious apps.  Personally I wouldn't be too concerned about a sophisticated hacker changing my XML, unless I was giving away prizes for achievements!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding file access:

Every Android App runs in it's own sandboxed environment with it's own system username. Data downloaded or residing in it's directory can not be read from other apps.

[Google Developers on Security](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html#userid) is worth reading.

In code, you can easily use

```
this.getFilesDir()
```

From within an activity subclass.

If a device is rooted or someone uses the adb shell from the sdk to access the app data directory, of course, he will be able to manipulate it, I assume.

Comment: but is it normal practice? like would angry bird have its level detail in an xml file, know that ppl can change the level details to win the game.

Comment: I dont know if it's common practice. Also I don't know if any data is really "safe" on a rooted device?

Comment: Anyways, when it's about XML documents, you could as well involve a web service returning the xml data or you make use of somehow binary xml files.